# Git ignore everything except custom theme directory

Tags: theme-development, git, github

I only just started trying to use GitHub with WordPress, so I'm completely new to everything git.

My problem is simple: I want to setup my .gitignore so git ignores absolutely everything except my Wordpress theme which is located at a custom directory '**/goods/themes/my-wordpress-theme**'.

I've tried a variety of .gitignore files such similar to the following and nothing works.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except 'my-wordpress-theme'
!goods/themes/my-wordpress-theme/*
```

I'm running Ubuntu with git version 2.7.4

Please help!
Thanks, Asher.

Comment: Just make that theme the git root, and don't even include upper directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run ignore on your `themes` directory and check out your themes to their individual directories. That will keep your theme segmented just as your WordPress environment. There is no sense in checking out a root git for a single theme.